# Show $n! \in O(n^n)$ but $n^n \notin O(n!). $

Tags: asymptotics

I'm not entirely sure if this proof would suffice, but here's what I have,

> $$\text{Show }n! \in O(n^n) \text{ but } n^n \notin O(n!).$$

Consider, $ c \geq\frac{|f(n)|}{g(n)}$ by Big O definition. Let $f(n) = n!$ and $g(n) = n^n \hspace{0.2cm}\forall n \geq 1$. Then $ c \geq \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \dfrac{|n!|}{n^n} = 0$. Next consider $f(n) = n^n$ and $g(n) = n!$. Then $ c \geq \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \dfrac{|n^n|}{n!} = \infty$. Hence, $n! \in O(n^n)$ but $n^n \notin O(n!)$ as required.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: You're asserting the two limits, but not proving that they are correct.  Also, what is $c$ in either case? In the second one, there is no such $c\in \mathbb{R}$ with $c\ge \infty$.

Comment: To make @Dr.MV's comment more precise, you have simply restated the question.

Comment: So I just need to show the limits are $0$ and $\infty$ respectively?

Comment: @Philip All you need to show, which is trivial, is $n!\le n^n$ and that $n^n\ge n\,n!$.  Then, $\frac{n!}{n^n}\le 1=C$ and $n!=O(n^n)$.  And $\frac{n^n}{n!}\ge n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is straightforward to show that $n^n\ge n\,n!$ (e.g., one can use induction).

---

Then we have

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}\le 1=C$$

and $n!=O(n^n)$.

---

On the other hand, we have

$$\frac{n^n}{n!}\ge n$$

Hence, for any fixed number $C>0$, however, large, there is a number $n>C$ such that $\frac{n^n}{n!}\ge n>C$, Therefore, **there is no number $C>0$** such that for sufficiently large $n$, $\frac{n^n}{n!}\le C$ and $n^n\ne O(n!)$.

And we are done!